# Evaluate the determinant

Tags: polynomials, determinant

Let the following determinant, where $f_i$ is a polynomial with order of at most $n-2$. Evaluate the determinant:
$$\left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {{f_1}({a_1})} & {{f_1}({a_2})} & {...} & {{f_1}({a_n})}  \\
   {{f_2}({a_1})} & {{f_2}({a_2})} & {...} & {{f_2}({a_n})}  \\
   {...} & {...} & {...} & {...}  \\
   {{f_n}({a_1})} & {{f_n}({a_2})} & {...} & {{f_n}({a_n})}  \\
\end{array}} \right|
$$

If I'm not mistaken, the answer is zero. That's of course pointless without a proof.

I tried to write down some specific examples to get a sense of what I am dealing with, yet it didn't lead to a significant progress. It looks like a tricky question so I am obviously missing something crucial.

Comment: Hint: any $n$ polynomials of degree at most $n-2$ are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set $\mathbb R_{n-2}[x]$ of polynomials with degree at most $n-2$ is a vector space with dimension $n-1$ so a family of $n$ polynomials in this space is linearly dependent hence the determinant is $0$.

Comment: WOW. just WOW..

Comment: You're welcome AndrePoole!

Comment: You WOWed the crowd, Sami!

Answer (score 1):

The map $f \mapsto f(a_1)$ is a *linear transformation* on the space of polynomials of degree at most $n-2$. In fact, given any $n-1$ distinct points, the map

$$ f \mapsto \left[\begin{matrix} f(a_1) \\ f(a_2) \\ \vdots \\ f(a_{n-1}) \end{matrix} \right] $$

computes the coordinate representation of $f$ with respect to some basis for the space of polynomials of degree at most $n-2$. (it's more work -- an "interpolation" algorithm -- to find that basis, but knowing the basis doesn't matter for this problem)

Answer (score 1):

Prove there are $k_2, k_3, \dots, k_n$ such that $\forall x : f_1(x) + \sum_{i=2}^n k_i f_i(x) = 0$.  Then you can multiply your matrix by this matrix (with determinant 1)
$$\left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   1 & {k_2} & \dots & {k_n}  \\
   0 & 1 & {...} & 0  \\
   {...} & {...} & {...} & {...}  \\
   0 & 0 & {...} & 1  \\
\end{array}} \right|$$

To get this one (with determinant 0):

$$\left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   0 & 0 & {...} & 0  \\
   {{f_2}({a_1})} & {{f_2}({a_2})} & {...} & {{f_2}({a_n})}  \\
   {...} & {...} & {...} & {...}  \\
   {{f_n}({a_1})} & {{f_n}({a_2})} & {...} & {{f_n}({a_n})}  \\
\end{array}} \right|$$